How to make a CSS grid that wraps when the container is too small?
I have a dynamic layout that will either have one or two items in it. I want each item take up half the width even when there is only a single item.

When there is not enough room for half the width to be greater than a min width (11rem), I want the items to take up the full width and wrap to the next line.

Ideally this can be done without media queries, so that the layout is dependent entirely on its own size rather than the full viewport size. I'm not sure whether this is a grid layout or a flexbox. I have not been able to get it working with either.


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(11rem, 1fr));
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
<div class="container">
  <input>
  <input>
</div>



How do I make a layout where each item takes up half the width in a large container and the full width in a small container?

From my article: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/


.container {
  --w: 400px; /* control when the items will wrap */
  
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 
    repeat(auto-fill, 
     minmax(clamp(100%/3 + 0.1%,(var(--w) - 100%)*1000,100%/2 + 0.1%),1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
<div class="container">
  <input>
  <input>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <input>
</div>




you can do this with flex. which should work
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.element1, .element2 {
  flex: 1 1 11rem;
}

for the single element, you could add a filler element in there with 0 height, as a second element, which should do the trick, or alternatively if you do not mind using newly available stuff you could look into container queries
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container
the filler element can also be done with pure css, again, if you don't mind relying on baseline newly available css selectors, namely has https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has
like this:
.container:has(>*:only-child)::after{
    content:"";
    flex: 1 1 11rem;
    height:0;
}


This does not work when there is a single item. The item will be the full width, but I need it to be half the width

@Eva see the text below the css. for 2 solutions i can think of.

The 0-height filler element works thanks

@Eva good to hear, i added a pure css option for that.

It doesn't work with only-child. I don't think the after pseudo element is considered a separate element for flexbox. It does work with a dummy div though

@Eva strange, did you use the exact selector that i used? for me it works, but you have to set flex: 1 1 11rem seperately on it, you can't expect that to be applied to it by doing something like .container>*

I'm using Tailwind in my real app, so I had to adjust it a little. flex-[1_1_11rem] only:after:flex-[1_1_11rem] only:after:h-0 only:after:content-[''] on the element. Devtools is showing the expected CSS applied in the after pseudo element, but the element still spans the full width

@Eva might i don't know anything about tailwind, nor that syntax, but i don't see anything about the "has" selector in there, are you sure this isn't selecting .container:only-child or something? cause then it would just select the container if it's the only child in its parent. but i see you found a better solution.

I put the class directly on the element not the container

@Eva if you put the class on the element the after will be at the end of the element, not after the element before will create an element at the beginning of an element not before and after will make an element at the end of the element, not after the element. if you get wat i mean, it will be put after the last child.

I did not notice that sorry. Yeah flex flex-wrap has-[:only-child]:after:flex-[11rem] on the container works

Your problem can be solved using media queries. In the code below, I have added a media query for when the screen size is smaller than the size of 2 minimum-width columns plus your maximum gap size (from clamp(0.5625rem, 0.5398rem + 0.1099vw, 0.625rem) in your comment. When the screen is smaller than that, then your grid-template-columns uses a repeat auto-fit instead of 2, which will automatically wrap your grid items to the next row if the current row can't fit them.


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(11rem, 1fr));
  gap: clamp(0.5625rem, 0.5398rem + 0.1099vw, 0.625rem);
}

/* Solution bit */
@media (max-width: 22.625rem) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(11rem, 1fr));
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <input>
  <input>
</div>




Is there a way to do it without media queries? This is based off the exact size of the gap and items in the example, but in my real app, the gap is clamp(0.5625rem, 0.5398rem + 0.1099vw, 0.625rem). I would prefer if the layout can be achieved based on its own size rather than the viewport size.

My best guest would be just taking the maximum gap value you have (0.625rem in your clamp), and adding that to the 22rem from the two columns to give you a static number. There is probably a way to solve this problem using JavaScript, but I'm still pretty new to that language, so I'm afraid I won't be much help. I've edited my answer to reflect the 22.625rem value for consistency's sake, and while it may not be 100% perfect, it should work for the bare minimum wrapping functions.
